# How tot get the position of current item in a recycler view outside the recycler adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am displaying a recycler view on the whole screen the recycler view has only item an image view i want to know how i can get the positon of the imageview shown on my screen outside the recycler adapter.

I have tried to implement an interface but the results are not accurate.I want to save the current position instantly.

My recycler adapter:

```
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHOlder> {
    private List<ImageList> mlist;
    private showPageNumber page;
    public RecyclerAdapter(List<ImageList> dataList, showPageNumber page) {
        mlist = dataList;
        this.page = page;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHOlder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHOlder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHOlder holder,int position) {
        Picasso.get().load(mlist.get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.photoView);
        page.showPage(position);
        holder.pageNumber.setText(position+1+"");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    class MyViewHOlder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView photoView;
        TextView pageNumber;

        public MyViewHOlder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            photoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdfImage);
            pageNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pageNumber);

        }
    }
    public interface showPageNumber{
        void showPage(int position);
    }
}
```

Whenever I implements the showPageNumber interface on my MainActivity the showPage method does't give accurate results on scrolling the items in recycler view.

Comment: I got the answer.By using findFirstVisibleitemPosition() I can get the required position

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you like to accomplish but if you like to find out which item is currently shown you might want to try this:

Assuming you are using a `LinearLayoutManager` on your RecyclerView you could listen to Scroll events an evaluate which page is shown when the ReclycerView settles after scrolling

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rcv);
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        // if you just want to know if the new "page" is completely visible
        if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING){
            int pagePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            // if you just want to know if the new "page" comes in view
            int pagePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I stumbled into this problem and I ran here, got disappointed with the output I got from other answers and here.
But here is what I found.
The concept behind it is to monitor where the recyclerview is going to and update a global variable. In my case I had cancelled scroll gestures on the recyclerView and I wanted it to only scroll smoothly when I press a button.
So, here I monitored the recyclerview position and updated my values accordingly.

```
//Global variable:

var rvPosition = 0
    onClick(v: View?){
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.schedule_previous -> {
                if (rvPosition > 0) {
                    smoothScroller.targetPosition = rvPosition - 1
                    binding.scheduleRv.layoutManager?.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
                    rvPosition -=1
                }
            }
            R.id.schedule_next -> {
                if (rvPosition < dataset.size) {
                    smoothScroller.targetPosition = rvPosition + 1
                    binding.scheduleRv.layoutManager?.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
                    rvPosition +=1
                }
            }
            R.id.schedule_users_card -> {}
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is creating a lambda that takes a value  (here it would be the item position), and assigns it to the variable you want.
Then, pass that lambda to the recycler and use it there to assign value to your variable.

That way, now you have your variable value wherever you want.

Simple enough if I do say so myself ;)